# Start of my first project (looking for critiques, general tips, hate)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

This might not be the best place to do this, but I'll also ask - is there a similar place on the internet like Stack Overflow that is in a more forum specific setting that I should join?

Anyway, this is the first project I've started from scratch, outside of the projects in some of the free online bootcamps.

I was hoping to get some critiques as to what I could have done better to achieve the same results, if there is any bad practice etc....its really basic stuff so far.

Is using too many media queries bad practice?

One of the issues I'm running into is the responsive design. I don't think when its done the menu will look like it does right now on small screens, (will have to learn how to make a hamburger menu) but I've been playing with this anyway, and am having trouble controlling exactly when the flex items wrap. It's set up right now so the drop down links move to the bottom when the screen shrinks, but it doesn't really work unless the screen is small enough for the items to "fully wrap".

Also, it seems that using "flex basis" and "flex grow" have a very similar effect. I commented that section of the code with my old code to show what I mean. The idea is basically that not all menu items are the same width, etc...

Any advice would be appreciated.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: hsl(9, 41%, 19%);
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Bowlby One SC';
}

header {
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  color: hsl(9, 41%, 19%);
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(112, 98, 98);
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  background-color: hsl(9, 41%, 19%);
  color: darkgoldenrod;
  padding: 0.2em;
  justify-content: start;
}

.top h1 {
  flex-basis: 85%;
  margin-left: 0.2em;
}

.social {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

input {
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 10%;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  color: hsl(9, 41%, 19%);
  border: 2px solid rgb(112, 98, 98);
  border-radius: 1.3em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0.2em;
}

input:focus {
  width: 25%;
  font-family: 'Bowlby One SC';
  padding-left: 1em;
}

nav {
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(112, 98, 98);
}

.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: -0.5em;
}

logo {
  font-size: 2em;
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  /* flex-basis: 20%;*/
}

.wide {
  flex: 1 0 12.5%;
  align-self: end;
  /* flex-basis: 12.5%;*/
}

.main {
  flex: 1 0 7.5%
  /*flex-basis: 7.5%;*/
}


/*logo {
    flex: 3 0;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.wide {
    flex: 2 1;
}

.main {
    flex: 1 1;
}*/

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: hsl(9, 41%, 19%);
  padding: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li>a:hover {
  background: hsl(9, 41%, 19%);
  color: darkgoldenrod;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: dropanimate;
  animation-duration: 300ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes dropanimate {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.sub-menu {
  background-color: rgba(112, 98, 98, 0.8);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: hsl(9, 41%, 19%);
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid rgb(112, 98, 98);
}

.sub-menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.sub:hover>.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}


/*display block vs flex creates cool difference here */

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  nav {
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  logo {
    order: 1;
  }
  .wide {
    order: 4;
  }
  nav ul li {
    margin-bottom: -0.6em;
  }
  .main {
    order: 3;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .user-action {
    order: 2;
  }
  .social {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .top h1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    align-self: center;
  }
  input {
    width: 55%;
  }
  input:focus {
    width: 55%;
    font-family: 'Bowlby One SC';
    padding-left: 1em;
    font-size: 0.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bowlby+One+SC" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Deadbeat Music</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="top">
      <h1>Deadbeat</h1>

      <input type="text" id="search" class="fas fa-search" placeholder="&#xf002;" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='&#xf002;'" />
      <i class="social fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      <i class="social fas fa-envelope"></i>
      <i class="social fas fa-comments"></i>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="container">
        <!-- <li id="logo">Deadbeat</li>-->
        <li class="sub wide" id="mission"><a href="">Our Mission </a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Partner Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub wide"><a href="">Profiles</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" id="profiles">
            <li class="profile-types"><a href="">Bands</a></li>
            <li class="profile-types"><a href="">Labels</a></li>
            <li class="profile-types"><a href="">Promoters</a></li>
            <li class="profile-types"><a href="">Bloggers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="show" class="wide"><a href="">Book a Show</a></li>
        <li class="sub wide" id="record"><a href="">Make a Record</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="">For Bands</a></li>
            <li><a href="">For Labels</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main"><a href="">Press</a></li>
        <li class="main"><a href="">Forum</a></li>
        <li class="main user-action"><a href="">Login</a></li>
        <li class="main user-action" id="sign-up"><a href="">Sign Up!</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd suggest you to check out [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

**DISCLAIMER:**

Now I'll ask you: are you sure you want to create your own UX design from scratch? This might seem like a simple question, but it can be really hard if you don't have a perfect plan for what to do - maybe try out some UX frameworks such as Material Components for the Web or Bootstrap? Also, I would not suggest creating a professional website as your first ever project, I guess you should first do some experiments before that.

Ok, if you're still sure about what you're doing, here are some tips:

- Be coherent with the widths of elements that don't take up the whole page: don't shrink the search box proportionally to the page size
- If you are actually planning on designing your own UX, again, coherency is key: always use the same type of button, maybe with some tiny variation. For example, you may define a standard style for `.btn` (a class that you will apply to all of your buttons), but then set their height to an arbitrary amount if they are in navbars
- If you want to style a pre-existing element (eg. `input type="text"`) from scratch, then you might want to disable the default style (the "user agent stylesheet" in Chrome) either manually (for example by specifying `outline: none` in text inputs) or with `-webkit-appearance: none` on Webkit-enabled browsers

I hope I've been useful to you  (but mostly I hope I've understood your question). Again, maybe UX Stack Exchange is the best place if you carry on creating your own design.

**Update**

As [Sheshank S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9414889/sheshank-s) suggests, you should use a more pleasant color scheme. You might want to take a look at this guide; in my opinion, the most important part is that:

> Most well-designed websites today use plenty of white space in order to create a sense of freedom, spaciousness, and breathability.

Also take a look at the colors liked by the two sexes (brown and orange are disliked by both...).

Also, if you're still persevering in making your own UX design, you could consider reading Universal Principles of Design, by William Lidwell.

**Update again**

I've just realised that if a mod sees this, they're *definitely* going to move it to UX Stack Exchange. Whatever.

Comment: You should add to use a better color scheme